# C# out parameter problem in the get root method

Tags: c#, .net, out

This code below grabs 3 inputs from the console and then parses the numbers, after it then gets sent to `getRealRoots` method. which finds whether it has 2, 1 or no roots. The out parameters in the getrealroots are showing the following error:

> The out parameter 'r1' must be assigned to before control leaves the
>   current method
>
> The out parameter 'r2' must be assigned to before control leaves the current method

```
using System;

namespace Quadratic
{
    public class Program
    {
        static public void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Enter three numbers, (A,B,C)");
            Double? a = GetDouble();
            Double? b = GetDouble();
            Double? c = GetDouble();

            getRealRoots(a, b, c,out r1,out r2);
            //throw new NotImplementedException("implement main");
        }





        static public int getRealRoots(double A, double B, double C, out double? r1, out double? r2)
        {
            double discriminant = B * B - 4 * A * C;

            if (discriminant > 0)
            {
                 r1 = (-B + Math.Sqrt(discriminant)) / (2 * A);
                 r2 = (-B - Math.Sqrt(discriminant)) / (2 * A);
                Console.WriteLine("The equation " + GetQuadraticString(A, B, C) + " has two real roots:" + r1 + " " + r2);
            }
            else if (discriminant == 0)
            {
                r1 = -B / (2 * A);
                Console.WriteLine("The equation " + GetQuadraticString(A, B, C) + " has one real root:" + r1);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The equation " + GetQuadraticString(A, B, C) + " has no real roots:");
            }

        }

        //throw new NotImplementedException("write a method that uses out variables to return the real discriminants of a quadratic");

    }
}
```

[image: error message that pops up]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you have the return type int, but do not return an int.

Second, the error message says that you have to assign your out parameters some value no matter what path of execution your method takes. You could solve this by assigning them some "default" values at the beginning of the method. Maybe like this?:

```
r1 = default (double);
r2 = null;
```

Hope I could help

Answer (score 1):

As [per the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/out-parameter-modifier) on the out parameter modifier:

> Variables passed as out arguments do not have to be initialized before being passed in a method call. **However, the called method is required to assign a value before the method returns.**

In the case of your provided code, in the method `getRealRoots`, you are:

- Setting the out value of `r1` and `r2` where `discriminant > 0`
- Setting the out value of `r1` where `discriminant == 0`, but not the value of `r2`
- Not setting `r1`, or `r2` where none of the above conditions are met.

As the called method is **required** to assign a value, you **must** set the value of `r1` and `r2` in each execution pathway.

As you have defined the values as a nullable type, you can begin your method with some default values to resolve your issue:

```
static public int getRealRoots(double A, double B, double C, out double? r1, out double? r2)
{
    r1 = null;
    r2 = null;

    // ... your method code
}
```

The default values are then overwritten under the specific IF conditions you have set.